# How to use multiple routes and multiple param converter with Symfony

Tags: symfony, routes

Is it possible to use **ParamConverter** with different classes depending on the route being called ?
Let's say I have a parent class `Food` with two children `Fruit` class and `Vegetable` class.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
    /**
     *
     * @Route("fruit/{id}", name="fruit_show")
     * @ParamConverter("food", class="AppBundle:Fruit")
     * @Route("vegetable/{id}", name="vegetable_show")
     * @ParamConverter("food", class="AppBundle:Vegetable")
     */
     public function showAction(Food $food)
     { ... }
```

Comment: That's not logical that you will show two separate objects, but use id for passing which can duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I found here is that the ParamConverter uses the last item in the annotations. If it matches the `fruit_show` route, the $food variable is an instance of the AppBundle:Vegetable class. That's the same if it matches the `vegetable_show` route.

```
class FoodController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/items/fruits/{id}", methods={"GET"}, name="fruits_show")
     * @ParamConverter("food", class="AppBundle:Fruit")
     * @Route("/items/vegetables/{id}", methods={"GET"}, name="vegetables_show")
     * @ParamConverter("food", class="AppBundle:Vegetable")
     */
    public function foodAction(Request $request, $food)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

> One workaround you can use is writing your own ParamConverter:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class FoodConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        $id = $request->get('id');
        $route = $request->get('_route');
        $class = $configuration->getOptions()[$route];

        $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), $this->entityManager->getRepository($class)->findOneById($id));

        return true;
    }

    public function supports(ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        return $configuration->getName() === 'food';
    }
}
```

Adding it to your services:

```
services:
    food_converter:
        class: App\SupportClasses\FoodConverter
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - {name: request.param_converter, priority: -2, converter: food_converter}
```

Using it like this:

```
class FoodController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/items/fruits/{id}", methods={"GET"}, name="fruits_show")
     * @Route("/items/vegetables/{id}", methods={"GET"}, name="vegetables_show")
     * @ParamConverter("food", converter = "food_converter" class="App:Food", options={"fruits_show" = "App:Fruit", "vegetables_show" = "App:Vegetable"})
     */
    public function foodAction(Request $request, $food)
    {
        var_dump($food);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Working nice after a few corrections: missing `arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']` in the services.yaml and missing `converter = food_converter` in the @ParamConverter annotation in the controller.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it is not possible to do exactly what you want. But it may be possible to get what you need with two simple wrapper actions. You won't even need an explicit `@ParamConverter` annotation. E.g.

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("fruit/{id}", name="fruit_show")
 */
 public function showFruitAction(Fruit $fruit)
 { 
    return $this->showAction($fruit)
 }

/**
 *
 * @Route("vegetable/{id}", name="vegetable_show")
 */
 public function showVegetableAction(Food $food)
 { 
    return $this->showAction($vegetable)
 }


public function showAction (Food $food)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Very nice trick, though I like Gimsly's answer better, because I want to use this in a whole controller, with 3 subclasses instead of 2, and your solution would result in a lot of methods/actions